# Why does removing a filter with ALL repeat values in a visual matrix?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm using the contoso DB and I have a measure that removes the filter on product category.

```
Sales PCT Calculate 3 = CALCULATE(
                           SUM(Sales[SalesAmount]),
                           ALL('Product Category')
                        )
```

My matrix has product category, subcategory on the rows. And the sum of sales amount with the measure above on the columns. When expanding the matrix to show the subcategory level, all the values are repeated for every category. Doesn't my measure mean the filters for the subcategory level are still in the filter context? I've tried playing with the measures for a while and I'm at the point where it's like semantic satiation but with dax.
[image: Matrix Visual]

Comment: That's an odd result. Did you merge the Category and Subcategory tables into the Product dimension, so you have (ProductKey, Product Name, ProductCategory, ProductSubcategory...) ? Maybe that's the problem, because if I add those to the Product table, it summarizes fine. (And they're maybe a mini-dimension at best, and can be logically incorporated into the Product dimension table.

Comment: The other thing that looks unusual is that you have one giant fact table... I'd just leave all the dimensions (Product, but include Category and Subcategory) etc. You don't really gain anything by creating a huge fact table with tons of columns. Leave that in the dimensions and leverage relationships.

Comment: The filters for subcategories are still in filter context. The ALL('Product Category') removes the filter on the Product Category. As a result, each Product Category line in the the visual isn't going to reflect the number for the Product Category (but rather the number for ALL categories). Correspondingly, each of the subcategories are NOT being filtered by the category either.  So each subcategory is showing the total number for that subcategory across all categories.  This is why the numbers repeat for each Category; because the calculation can't see the category. @Pieter